# Размещение картинки

Tags: css, img

Как разместить картинку в блоке? Я пробовала создать новый класс, но у меня он размещается ниже нужного синего блока.

```css
.card {
  float: right;
}

.inform {
  width: 770px;
  height: 302px;
  background: #184c6b;
  color: #c0ddee;
  border-radius: 13px;
}

.text {
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-left: 37px;
  width: 386px;
  height: 302px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="inform">
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Заголовок карточки</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos dolorem recusandae fugiat, blanditiis eveniet incidunt pariatur quibusdam natus quam facilis voluptatum tenetur et, quia eos aspernatur non magnam minima. Perferendis error assumenda
        sapiente pariatur harum tempora autem, ullam blanditiis quibusdam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: ][1]]

Answer (score 0):

**Если правильно понял.** 
https://codepen.io/AndreyMyP/pen/eyqmMj

```
.block-1 { float: left; }
.block-2 { float: right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на флексах
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LewVvy

```css
h3 {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card {
  float: right;
  width: 770px;
  height: 302px;
  padding: 20px 37px;
  background: #184c6b;
  border-radius: 13px;
  color: #c0ddee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h3>Заголовок карточки</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos dolorem recusandae fugiat, blanditiis eveniet incidunt pariatur quibusdam natus quam facilis voluptatum tenetur et, quia eos aspernatur non magnam minima. Perferendis error assumenda
        sapiente pariatur harum tempora autem, ullam blanditiis quibusdam.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/380769/pexels-photo-380769.jpeg" width="250px">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, sit?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```